# Mockito verifying method invocation without using equals method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito, stub

While using Spock i can do something like this:

```java
when:
12.times {mailSender.send("blabla", "subject", "content")}

then:
12 * javaMailSender.send(_)
```

When i tried to do same in Mockito:

```java
verify(javaMailSender,times(12)).send(any(SimpleMailMessage.class))
```

I got an error that SimpleMailMessage has null values, so i had to initialize it in test:

```java
SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage()
simpleMailMessage.setTo("blablabla")
simpleMailMessage.subject = "subject"
simpleMailMessage.text = "content"
verify(javaMailSender,times(12)).send(simpleMailMessage))
```

Now it works but it's a large workload and i really don't care about equality. What if SimpleMailMessage will have much more arguments or another objects with another arguments, meh. Is there any way to check that send method was just called X times?

EDIT: added implementation of send method.

```java
private fun sendEmail(recipient: String, subject: String, content: String)
{
    val mailMessage = SimpleMailMessage()

    mailMessage.setTo(recipient)
    mailMessage.subject = subject
    mailMessage.text = content

    javaMailSender.send(mailMessage)
}
```

There are 2 senders, mailSender is my custom object and javaMailSender is from another libary

Stacktrace:

```
Mockito.verify(javaMailSender, 
Mockito.times(2)).send(Mockito.any(SimpleMailMessage.class))
    |      |                       |         |            |
    |      |                       |         |            null
    |      |                       |         Wanted but not invoked:
    |      |                       |         javaMailSender.send(
    |      |                       |             <any org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage>
    |      |                       |         );
    |      |                       |         -> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    |      |                       |          
    |      |                       |         However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:
    |      |                       |         javaMailSender.send(
    |      |                       |             SimpleMailMessage: from=null; replyTo=null; to=blabla; cc=; bcc=; sentDate=null; subject=subject; text=content
    |      |                       |         );
    |      |                       |         -> at MailSenderServiceImpl.sendEmail(MailSenderServiceImpl.kt:42)
    |      |                       |          
    |      |                       |         javaMailSender.send(
    |      |                       |             SimpleMailMessage: from=null; replyTo=null; to=blabla; cc=; bcc=; sentDate=null; subject=subject; text=content
    |      |                       |         );
```

Comment: What are the parameters of `send`? In the first example, you have shown three strings while in the second you have an object

Comment: parameter is SimpleMailMessage. method mailSender.send(String, String, String) internally initialize SimpleMailMessage in the way as in 2nd example.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that code fragment. Can you give more details as to where it said it had null values?

Comment: added stacktrace, as you see. It need the equality SimpleMailMessage but i just want to check: "did method was called 12 times?" I dont care for equality of SimpleMailMessage

Comment: Could you please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just an set of incoherent snippets? E.g. in your test I do not see the equivalent to `mailSender.send("blabla", "subject", "content")`. BTW, I removed the _spock_ tag because this definitely is no Spock question.

Comment: I think the problem was Groovy. ArgumentMatchers.any(Class<T> type) method doesn't works when i put there SimpleMailMessage.class written in Groovy. But when I did it in Java file it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for the parameter of send, leave any() empty:

```
verify(javaMailSender,times(12)).send(any())
```

Comment: and do it in Spock (Groovy) and it won't work. No idea why : /

Comment: so you combine spock and mockito?
could you provide the mockito version you're using? i'd like to check it

Comment: yeah because Mockito (with a plugin) is able to mock final classes and half of my project is in Kotlin (which has final as default). So when I need to mock Kotlin class then using Mockito.
I have mockito-core 2.11.0 as dependency